# Configure docker to create folders with container name instead of container Id

Tags: python, docker, containers

Docker stores container metadata in `/var/lib/docker/containers/{container ID}/....` folder. Container ID as well as container name are both unique in a docker environment, so is it possible to configure docker daemon so I get the folders with container names as `/var/lib/docker/containers/{container name}...` instead of container ID ?

This would be useful to me in cases where I have to recreate a container many times, in such cases container ID will change every time but container name remains the same.

Comment: In general you should never be manually poking around in `/var/lib/docker`.  The content of the `containers` directory tree is going to be installation-specific and could change across versions of Docker.  What's the higher-level task you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I was trying to read container logs through an agent on my VM but as I have to recreate the container many times, I have to also change the agent configuration each time. I can read the logs from docker-volumes as well but for some containers, writing logs to file is tiresome process